# Golang Gorm Fiber - How can I send the name I defined as alias to my index template?

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-templates, go-fiber, go-html-template

I'm trying to switch from PHP to GO, but I'm stuck at one point, I ask for your help.

I just define an alias named "durums" in the query, there is no such named field in the database.  how can I send the name I defined as alias to my index template?

```
    Vilan := []model.Vfilan{}

    dSubquery := r.DB.Table("Dipfilan").
        Select("(select id from iform where id = Dipfilan.id and actv='1' )as uuid ").
        Where("tur = '2' AND finish > ?", time.Now())

    errIlan := r.DB.Table("Vfilan").
        Select("id, baslik,durumid, "+
            "(SELECT title FROM idurum WHERE idurum .id = Vfilan.durumid) as durums").
        Where("onay = '1'  AND (id IN ? )", dSubquery).
        Order("id DESC").
        Find(&Vilan).
        Error


    if errIlan != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "err" + errIlan.Error(),
        })
    }


    return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
        
        "VindwIlan": Vilan,

        "Vdurum": durums, 
    })
```

> "Vdurum": durums,  I get the error undeclared name: durums

How can I send the "durums" content to my index template.

Can you share the full error message?
undeclared name: durums

Can you specify on which line you are getting this error?

```
return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
           "VindwIlan": Vilan,
    "Vdurum": durums, 
})
```

Comment: An alias in a query is only meaningful for the database executing that query. When you get the results in a variable, which appears to be `vilan`, the db values are assigned to go variables with matching names, or with matching tags. Is there a field `durums` in ``Vilan`?

Comment: In the model structure of my "Vilan" table, there is no field named "durums". I define this field as an alias within the query. How can I assign the alias I defined within the query to a render?

Comment: You have to assign that to a Go variable like you did with `Vilan`. You seem to be using Gorm, though, I am not sure if it supports processing such queries. You seem to be expecting multiple items for that column.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GORM.

Actually, what I want to achieve is to match the value I assigned as "id" in my main table "Vilan" with the "id" in my "idurum" table and print the title from the "idurum" table. I've performed a join, but when I send it to render and I write the "Vilan" that I defined at the top, the alias I wrote as "durums" in my index template is not being sent with the render

Comment: Your program does not know the names you use in  query. You have to get that value to a go variable. Then you can use it in a map

Comment: I solved my problem. I shared the answer. Thank you for your support.